# Php for each statement

Tags: php, foreach

my code looks like this

```
echo '<table border="2" > <th> locked </th> ';
$picksquery = mysql_query("SELECT `column`, `column` FROM table WHERE username='username' ");

 $pickresults= mysql_fetch_assoc($picksquery);
 foreach ($pickresults as $data)

  {
    echo $data. '<br/>';


}
echo ' </table>';


?>
```

my problem is that it is echoing out multiple entries. (for example. the array is (a,b) and I am getting four entries with a,a,b,b. Anyone know what I could be doing wrong? The database is accurate and doesn't have multiple entries.

Comment: I updated it and now it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing echo $data[0];

Comment: ahhh. i caught my own error. I need to do mysql_fetch_assoc. That has got me the correct results.